# Need first day of last month and Last day of next month from current date in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

Need first day of last month and Last day of next month from current date in Asp.Net
Eg : Current date 02/12/2019 
first day of last month = 01/11/2019
Last day of next month = 31/01/2020

Comment: no date exist like `31/11/2020`

Comment: thanks for the correction ,its a clerical mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var myDate = DateTime.Now;
        var firstDateOfLastMonth = myDate.AddMonths(-1);
        firstDateOfLastMonth = firstDateOfLastMonth.AddDays(-firstDateOfLastMonth.Day + 1);
        var lastDayOfNextMonth = myDate.AddMonths(1);
        lastDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(lastDayOfNextMonth.Year, lastDayOfNextMonth.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(lastDayOfNextMonth.Year, lastDayOfNextMonth.Month));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to refer [DataTime C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/datetime-in-c-sharp/) for more info

please try below line of code:

```
 DateTime lastMonthdate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
 var lastMonth = new DateTime(lastMonthdate.Year, lastMonthdate.Month, 1);
 var lastDayOfNextMonth = lastMonth.AddYears(1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```